# validator.w3.org reports a markup error - detected character encoding "utf-8"

Tags: html, internet-explorer, doctype

validator.w3.org reports for www.besaltnlight.ca:

Character Encoding Override in effect!
The detected character encoding "utf-8" has been suppressed and "iso-8859-1" used instead.

The php code outputs iso-8859-1 and php sets that as the default characterset.

What is causing this problem? Am I using the wrong doctype?

Oh, and would any of this cause quirks mode in IE?

Thanks for your help.

Gerry

Answer (score 2):

The document is encoded in UTF-8. It has a byte order mark, smart quotes, and an ellipsis, all properly encoded in UTF-8. It begins with *two* byte order marks, which is invalid. You must remove one, and the validator also says that the presence of a BOM in a UTF-8 document may be confusing, so you may remove them both.

Since you’re outputting UTF-8, you must change the HTTP header to:

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Since you are missing that header, you force the browser to guess. Additionally, the meta tag must be changed to

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

Your output starts with a Unicode byte order mark, encoded in UTF-8.

This is likely the first some bytes of your PHP file, or any PHP file included by your main file. Your editor may not even show them. Interpreted as ISO-8859-1 the start of the output looks like `ï»¿ï»¿<!DOCTYPE html`, which are even **two** byte order marks, one after each other.

As said by jleedev, either make sure your files are really encoded in Latin-1, or declare the encoding as UTF-8.

Comment: ŭlo: I am not outputting any utf BOM. The validator says correctly that some older browsers do not support it, so I am trying to get everything output as ISO-8859-1...

Comment: Then use another editor which does not automatically add BOMs to the PHP files you are editing - and configure your editor to save as Latin 1 (ISO-8859-1).  (It might be this BOM is in one of the library files you are including.)